# razor version error when downgrading mvc project

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I was working on a site in mvc4 using visual studio express 2012.  Due to reasons I won't bother getting into here, I have to move the project back to mvc3 vs 2010.  I have all the code moved over and compiling but when I run the project I get the following error. I have no idea what to do here.  Anyone have a guess?  Thanks.

> [A]System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection cannot be cast
>   to [B]System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection. Type A
>   originates from 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' in the context
>   'Default' at location
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.WebPages.Razor\v4.0_2.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll'.
>   Type B originates from 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' in the context
>   'Default' at location
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.WebPages.Razor\v4.0_1.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll'.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidCastException: [A]System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection cannot be cast
>   to [B]System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection. Type A
>   originates from 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' in the context
>   'Default' at location
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.WebPages.Razor\v4.0_2.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll'.
>   Type B originates from 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' in the context
>   'Default' at location
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.WebPages.Razor\v4.0_1.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll'.

In my root web.config I have the following...

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="1.0.0.0" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
```

Then in the web.config in the views folder I have...

```
<appSettings>
   <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
</appSettings>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not seeing your web.config I'm not certain if this is correct. But this error message points to the `webpages:config` setting being incorrect. Therefore please try the following:

In your web.config change the following

```
<appSettings>
    ...
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
    ....
</appSettings>
```

to

```
<appSettings>
    ....
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="1.0.0.0" />
    ....
</appSettings>
```

### UPDATE

Another possible cause of this error is the binding redirects that MVC4 adds by default, i.e.

```
<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

Please remove the above from your web.config and replace it with

```
<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

Comment: I've updated my question with the web.config code you referred to.  I did find that as a possible solution before I posted but it didn't seem to work for me.  Should I have this in the root's web.config or in the web.config that's in the views directory?  Actually, I tried both and neither worked.

Comment: Okay it looks like my solution doesn't work for you. Another possible problem area could be your runtime section. I'll update my answer with another possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

Penfold, thanks for trying to help.  Although neither of your solutions were the fix, they pointed me in the right direction.  I had a couple of blocks in my view's web.config file that were leftover from the original mvc4 and needed updated to mvc3.  I started a new mvc3 project and copied over the defaults and it worked.  Here's what I changed.

```
<configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
```

I changed the above to this.

```
<configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
```